# What is the cognitive architecture with the highest IIT measure?

Tags: reference-request, cognitive-architecture, integrated-information-theory

What contemporary information system or [cognitive architecture](http://bicasociety.org/cogarch/architectures.php) is the one with the highest measure of the [Integrated Information Theory (IIT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory) (that is, a theory of consciousness, which states that a system's consciousness is determined by its causal properties and is, therefore, an intrinsic, fundamental property of any physical system)

Is there race/competitions to develop (or allow autonomous development) the system with the maximum IIT measure?